# Formatting of programmatically generated jupyter markdown lists and tables inside loops

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter

I want to programmatically generate a report using Jupyter and need to put variables inside of markdown tables. I found this related answer: [Related Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288670/how-to-programmatically-generate-markdown-output-in-jupyter-notebooks).

However, if you put the code inside a for loop, the table and list are not formatted as desired (tested in Google Colab, Pycharm and Jupyter Notebook).

```
from IPython.display import display_markdown

for i in range(2):
    display_markdown(f'''## heading
    - ordered
    - list

    The table below:

    | id |value|
    |----|-----|
    | a  | {i} |
    | b  |  2  |
    ''', raw=True)
```

Tested code in Jupyter Notebook, Pycharm and Google Colab. The code delivers properly formatted text if used outside of for loop.

**Edit**
This question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562350/what-is-causing-triple-quotes-to-change-the-indentation) describes the underlying problem. However, I believe that the different context (markdown formatting) and the is helpful for future searches.

Comment: Your formatting of the string to be aligned with the indentation of the `for` loop causes there to be extra leading spaces in the string which messes up the markdown. You have to omit the indentation from the string.

Answer (score 0):

As mkrieger's comments get out, the problem is with the extra spacing you added at the start of lines:

This version hews very close to yours and yet works:

```py
from IPython.display import display_markdown

for i in range(2):
    display_markdown(f'''## heading
- ordered
- list

The table below:

| id |value|
|----|-----|
| a  | {i} |
| b  |  2  |
''', raw=True)
```

I simply removed the extra spaces at the start of the lines after the first.

---

Here is a version of your code looping with a string replacement to accomplish the same thing:

```py
s='''## heading
- ordered
- list

The table below:

| id |value|
|----|-----|
| a  | PLACEHOLDER_FOR_VALUE |
| b  |  2  |'''

# code based on https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-dictionary-content-output-format/5863/2?u=fomightez
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
def printmd(string):
    display(Markdown(string))
for i in range(2):
    printmd(s.replace("PLACEHOLDER_FOR_VALUE",f"{i}"))
```

I'm using the variation of making markdown from a string that I am familiar with, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-dictionary-content-output-format/5863/2?u=fomightez).

---

By the way. If you are looking to assemble reports using Jupyter, **nbformat** is something you may want to look into.

The intro at the top of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004) will probably help you see how nbformat might be helpful for what you. Importantly, the abstractions of the notebook & cells & types of cells is all baked in and you can easily output new notebooks with contents as you design programmatically.

See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/search?q=%40fomightez%20nbformat%20order%3Alikes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a8508004%20nbformat&searchOn=3) for more examples with code.